Autofac DI and "Child" Scopes
I have a project where I use Autofac to create UI components.
I would like some of my Autofac-created UI components to have child components that can potentially reference their parent.
What is the right way of doing this such that Autofac-specifics don't leak into my application?  Ideally, I'd like a way of basically saying:
Create a new scope that inherits all items in the current scope and registers A, B, and C.  
From that new scope, create A.

Any ideas?
(I'd would like to avoid making my components aware of autofac things.  If I could create a Func<???> that would handle all this, that would be awesome.

I don't think you're going to find an easy or clean way to do what you're looking to do.
You are likely going to have to write your own abstraction around the operations so your main app code talks to your abstraction, then your abstraction talks to Autofac. Think like a factory class or something similar.
I don't even know what that would look like. There's no way to propose anything because you didn't include any pseudo-code to show what you thought a good idea might be.
I imagine in the simplest terms you might have an interface like:
public interface IComponentResolver
  : IDisposable
{
  T Resolve<T>(params Type[] registrations);
}

Your implementation would...

Take a lifetime scope in the constructor. This is the base from which other scopes are forked.
Do the create scope, register things, resolve from child in the Resolve method implementation.
Track all the lifetime scopes it creates and dispose of them in the Dispose method.

This is, of course, pretty simple and doesn't actually give you all the power of Autofac in the registrations. The more you need, the more work you have to do.
Before doing that, I might ask myself if this is worth the effort. I recognize some folks desire to abstract away any connection with external libraries for various reasons. I might ask myself if those reasons are practical. For example, if the goal is to be able to swap Autofac out for something later... How many other DI containers do what you're asking to do, and when do you think you'd do that swap? Is the effort now worth the extra work?
Do you isolate yourself from every library you touch? Got your own logger interface, your own UI abstraction around the framework components, your own JSON serializer wrapper, etc? That sounds like a lot of YAGNI.
But that's just my opinion. Maybe the extra work is worth it, and if so, you have some custom factory code to write. Maybe it's not, in which case you can spend more time writing features and less worrying about the few spots tied to a specific library.
